# How do I install Stellar-core?

Tags: stellar-core

[image: Directory listing]

I installed stellar-core through the source code and I don't know how to proceed.
Do you have any good suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The instructions are in the source. Read the file `INSTALL.md`.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this [link](https://labs.imaginea.com/post/stellar-bc-wallet/) for connecting two nodes. Using this you can create your own Private network setup with 2 nodes running (self-validating) and one REST server running. And for basic installation also follow this [link](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/INSTALL.md).